# Find handle of other application's ListBox using Winforms

Tags: c#, handle, sendmessage

In my current winforms project I'm trying to make a selection in another application's listbox, using SendMessage

I'v successfully found the correct main window and send it commands. I can't however find the handle to the control of the listbox.

Using the FindWindowEx function, or using Winspy++ I can only get a handle of a part of the window which holds multiple listbox and a few buttons.

How would I get a handle to the correct listbox, so I could use SendMessage and LB_SELITEMRANGEEX to select a certain item in it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the other application is written in .NET, then this is most likely because some .NET System.Windows.Forms are rendered graphically rather than being registered as actual Windows controls.  This was originally because of divergence between .NET Forms and Windows, where .NET was trying to provide control features that were not supported by the version of Windows at the time.  Now, this divergence seems to be preserved only because the two groups are so completely incompatible that trying to reconcile them isn't worth the cost, but whether that is true is yet to be seen.

Note that LB_SELITEMRANGEEX isn't likely to be understood by the custom .NET control even if you could figure out a way to send it a message.

I suggest trying to find out how the child controls are owned by the Windows container control that you can see (a grouping control wrapped in a .NET Panel object), to confirm or refute this theory, since .NET may be obfuscating the control hierarchy for no apparent reason except to be different.  Especially watch event messages when you click around the listbox, to determine if normal Windows control messages are being passed.

If these are custom .NET controls that aren't registered as Windows controls, your options are limited.  .NET relies mostly on pointers to event callbacks to manage events, rather than the built-in Windows message system.  The CLR instance for each running Windows application is separate.  Even if you can get a pointer to the Form object, you won't be able to use that across applications, since they do not share a managed heap or even a virtual memory space.

If you have control over development of the applications, you can add externally-visible messaging to help with this, but I assume you don't since you wouldn't need to send a message like this if you did.  You may still be able to figure out what messages to send, and where to send them, if the particular controls have a messaging interface that passes through the Windows messaging system, which is possible, since most of those controls were originally built directly on top of Windows controls, and then later diverged.